# Identificar Resize de controle filho

Tags: c#, winforms

Olá. Estou passando pelo seguinte cenário. Eu tenho um UserControl que tem largura dinâmica baseada no texto digitado em um TextBox dentro do mesmo. Para isso no evento TextChanged desse TextBox, é feito o seguinte algorítimo:

```
private void MensurarTamanho()
    {
        var tamanho = TextRenderer.MeasureText(txtLyric.Text, txtLyric.Font).Width + txtLyric.Margin.Horizontal + 2;
        var tamanhomin = cbChord.Width + btopc.Width + checkBox1.Width + 6;

        Width = tamanho < tamanhomin ? tamanhomin : tamanho;
    }
```

Esse controle é enfileirado dentro de um FlowLayoutPanel (Que representa um grupo de controles) que por sua vez é Efileirado em um outro FlowLayoutPanel (Ou seja, um FlowLayoutPanel com FlowLayoutPanels como controles filhos.
Para que a largura do FlowLayoutPanel se ajuste e seja dinâmica conforme os controles são adicionados eu utilizei o seguinte código nos eventos ControlAdded e ControlRemoved:

```
private void flowLayoutPanel1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        var maior = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Control>().OrderBy(c => c.Height).LastOrDefault();

        var largura = 6 + flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Control>().Sum(c => c.Width + c.Margin.Horizontal);
        int altura = 120;

        if (maior != null)
        {
            altura = maior.Height + maior.Margin.Vertical;
        }

        Size = new Size(largura, altura);
    }
```

Isso funciona perfeitamente quando adiciono e removo controles, contudo, os controles internos se ajustam conforme o texto é editado, como já descrito no inicio. Nesse caso eu preciso identificar quando um controle interno é redimensionado para que eu possa aplicar o algorítimo de redimensionamento acima novamente.
Eu pensei em adicionar um delegate no evento Resize a cada controle filho adicionado e remover o delegate sempre que um controle for removido, Porém busco uma forma mais elegante de fazer isso.

Segue abaixo print:
[image: Print do cenário real]

Comment: Exatamente. Eu poderia utilizar os eventos "ControlAdded" e "ControlRemoved" para atribuir os delegates aos eventos Resize dos controles filhos. Contudo, estava procurando uma forma mais elegante de fazer isso.

Comment: Explicarei com essa imagem: https://i.imgur.com/IcQLV1q.png

E como a explicação é longa e o comentário não me dá muitos caracteres, eis aqui a explicação: https://pastebin.com/uniqPetB

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/7kP5ZNM.png
Esse é o método acionado pelo "ControlAdded" e "ControlRemoved". Ele funciona perfeitamente quando estou adicionando ou removendo um controle. Porém preciso invocar o mesmo toda vez que um controle filho for redimensionado. (desculpe a qualidade do código, é um código de teste)

Comment: Farei as edições, desculpe, sou novato no comunidade.

Comment: Sim. Não funciona para esse cenário.

Comment: certo, tente colocar o mais explicado possível, na pergunta mesmo, e coloque o código que você já fez, como código mesmo e não print screen. Use print screen apenas para a tela. Esse monte de comentário, vou apagar depois

Comment: Pergunta editada.